What can interfere with the work of AnyIp
I'm trying to enable the anyip kernel function but for some reason it doesn't want to work on vps.
I ordered myself a VPS with an ipv6/64 subnet
all addresses work in this subnet if you add them manually.
my ip -6 a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a09:7c44:0:de::1/32 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe67:ff9b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

what I did

added route: ip -6 route add local 2a09:7c44:0:de::/64 dev lo

this should be enough to work, but it is not. I can ping from the remote server only this address 2a09:7c44:0:de::1 (but I can't ping any ip)
but all addresses from this subnet are pinged locally
my route tables:
root@vm2171415:~# ip -6 route show table 255
local ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a09:7c44:0:de::1 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a09:7c44:0:de::/64 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
local fe80::5054:ff:fe67:ff9b dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

and i check any address:
root@vm2171415:~# ip -6 route get 2a09:7c44:0:de::6
local 2a09:7c44:0:de::6 from :: dev lo table local src 2a09:7c44:0:de::1 metric 1024 pref medium

I also tried using different programs that work with anyip, for example, freebind, but they do not work.
Can you tell me what could be preventing this function from working?
ping result From 2a09:7c44:0:de::1 to 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3
root@vm2171415:~# ping6 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3
PING 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3(2a09:7c42:0:3a::3) 56 data bytes
From 2a03:afc0:8:200::2 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
^C
--- 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 18385ms

and result tcpdump in 2a09:7c42:0:3a::
root@vm2180722:~# tcpdump -n -i ens3 "icmp6"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:39:33.231503 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:19e8: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::19e8, length 32
22:39:33.496324 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:109::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:33.579246 IP6 2a13:6305:0:12::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a13:6305::1, length 32
22:39:34.095786 IP6 2a09:7c42::69d > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:34.188954 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:19e8: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::19e8, length 32
22:39:34.449222 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:e0::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:35.188243 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:b286: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::b286, length 32
22:39:35.188690 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:19e8: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::19e8, length 32
22:39:35.803067 IP6 2a09:7c42::2e8 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:35.938031 IP6 2a09:7c42::388 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:36.188444 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:4aa1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::4aa1, length 32
22:39:36.190469 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:b286: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::b286, length 32
22:39:37.188840 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:4aa1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::4aa1, length 32
22:39:37.196184 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:b286: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::b286, length 32
22:39:37.733931 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:f6::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:38.188985 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:4aa1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::4aa1, length 32
22:39:39.124185 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:107::10 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:41.565597 IP6 2a09:7c42::145 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:42.727165 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:2b::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:43.202794 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:3: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3, length 32
22:39:43.234433 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:bf::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:44.198568 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:3: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3, length 32
22:39:45.197765 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:629c: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:1e::629c, length 32
22:39:45.197766 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:728b: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::728b, length 32
22:39:45.197766 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:3: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:3a::3, length 32
22:39:45.645281 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:cf::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:46.198009 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:728b: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::728b, length 32
22:39:46.198010 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:629c: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:1e::629c, length 32
22:39:46.827211 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:14::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:47.197652 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:629c: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:1e::629c, length 32
22:39:47.197653 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:728b: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::728b, length 32
22:39:48.221917 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:1cf6: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::1cf6, length 32
22:39:49.196819 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:1cf6: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::1cf6, length 32
22:39:49.689227 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:79:: > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:49.766867 IP6 2a09:7c42::501 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:49.935465 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:9d::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:50.197961 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:1cf6: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:50::1cf6, length 32
22:39:50.197962 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:da96: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::da96, length 32
22:39:50.465006 IP6 2a09:7c42:0:c3::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42::1, length 32
22:39:50.487799 IP6 fe80::5054:ff:fef7:be07 > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
22:39:51.197624 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:da96: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::da96, length 32
22:39:51.197624 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:5429: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:1e::5429, length 32
22:39:52.088695 IP6 2a13:6305:0:b::1 > ff02::1:ff00:1: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a13:6305::1, length 32
22:39:52.196536 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:da96: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:23::da96, length 32
22:39:52.196536 IP6 fe80::d207:ca00:fa32:aa00 > ff02::1:ff00:5429: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a09:7c42:0:1e::5429, length 32


Is your /64 routed to you, or is it configured "on-link"? That is, 1) does ping report "Host unreachable" or does it just time out? 2) if you do tcpdump -n -i ens3 "icmp6" and then have someone ping any of your addresses, do you see the actual Echo Request from ping, or do you see a Neighbor Solicitation for that address instead?

@u1686_grawity ping from another server just waits. Doesn't report anything. The tcpdump also does not receive packets from the remote server. But everything works if ping the address that is configured (2a09:7c44:0:de::1)

Does it not receive any Neighbor Solicitations from your datacenter's router either?

@u1686_grawity I ordered another VPS but they allocated me another subnet /16. Ping from the new server also doesn't work. I tried to set up anyip on a new vps and it also doesn't work. Ping to this new server says: From 2a03:afc0:8:200::2 icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable I just don't understand why From isn't my IP

Literally because the error message is "Destination unreachable", which implies that it must have come from a router along the way and not from the destination itself. It also strongly hints that the address is on-link, so I want to repeat my question about the tcpdump results.

The important point here is that stuff like routes, bind, anyip, etc. can only work on packets that reach the server at all. If the packets don't reach the server, then that needs to be fixed first, otherwise it's like swapping lightbulbs during a blackout.

@u1686_grawity the tcpdump shows that the packets are not coming from another server

Right, but I also want to know about packets from a router, not just from the other server. Does tcpdump for icmp6 show nothing at all or does it still show "ICMPV6 Neighbor Solicitation" from some 'fe80::' address?

@u1686_grawity there are many packages fe80:: (neighbor solicitation)

It might help if you were to update your question showing examples of the tcpdump output.

@Dmitriy Are any of them showing who has <pinged_ip>?

@u1686_grawity i updated question

Assigning an IP address to an interface doesn't just route it internally within the OS – it also makes the OS respond to IPv4 ARP or IPv6 Neighbor Discovery queries externally, which is what allows the datacenter's router forward packets to the server.
Your "any IP" configuration only does the former but not the latter, so without the Neighbor Discovery replies the router doesn't know which MAC address it should be forwarding the packets to. This is what leads to "Address unreachable" or "Host unreachable" errors.
Since the ping packets never get delivered to the server in the first place, the server of course can't respond to them.
So you'll need some way to send ND replies on behalf of the entire /64, aka "proxy NDP" or "proxy ARP" – such as the ndpresponder daemon, or the older nddpd. (I'd suggest trying ndpresponder first.)
Another way to avoid the problem would be to get a routed /64 if the server provider offers that, though often they don't. A routed prefix only needs ND/ARP response for a single address to which packets for the entire /64 would be delivered. (That's really the only difference though – it's a cleaner setup but the performance is identical, so ndpresponder/ndppd is acceptable.)
